# Issue with default Sorting on Virtual Table & ViewerComparator

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

We have a Virtual Table in my Eclipse RCP application. We make a call to the backend to retrieve the data to be populated in the virtual table.

We want default sorting on the table on a single column. We use ViewerComparator to achieve sorting functionality. My problem is, I am not able to get this sorting working when the table loads with  the data for the 1st time. But when I click on the column, everything works fine as expected.

This is how, I set the Comparator to the column

```
    TableViewerColumn tvc = viewer.addColumn(100, SWT.LEFT, "Name");
    viewer.setColumnComparator(tvc,
            new Comparator<Person>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Person o1,Person o2) {
                    double firstValue = Double.parseDouble(o1
                            .getAge());
                    double secondValue = Double.parseDouble(o2
                            .getAge());
                    return firstValue > secondValue ? 1 : -1;
                }
            });
```

setColumnComparator method in custom viewer

```
public void setColumnComparator(TableViewerColumn tvc, Comparator<T> cmp){
    final MyViewerComparator c = new MyViewerComparator(cmp);
    final TableColumn tc = tvc.getColumn();

    setComparator(c);
    getTable().setSortDirection(c.getDirection());
    getTable().setSortColumn(tc);
    refresh();

    tc.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                        <same code as above>
        }
    });
```

MyViewerComparator

```
class MyViewerComparator extends ViewerComparator{
    Comparator<T> cmp;
    boolean desc = true;
    MyViewerComparator(Comparator<T> cmp){
        this.cmp = cmp;
    }
    int getDirection(){
        return desc?SWT.UP:SWT.DOWN;
    }

    void flipDirection(){
        desc = !desc;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Viewer viewer, Object e1, Object e2) {
```

> **if(e1 == null || e2==null){**

```
            return 0;
        }
        int rc = cmp.compare((T)e1, (T)e2);
        if(desc)
            return -rc;
        return rc;
    }
}
```

When the table loads the data for the 1st time, it goes inside the **Bolded** condition in the above code as one of the object is **ALWAYS NULL**

**Note:** This functionality works totally fine if I use a Standard table rather than VIRTUAL TABLE. I am not sure whether I can change it to use Standard table as we want the lazy load functionality as well..

ContentProvider used is: ObservableListContentProvider

Please advise..

Comment: Would really appreciate if somebody can provide a solution to this issue? I am stuck with this issue for sometime and I really need to find a solution to this one

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/288720/

Answer (score 1):

A late answer that hopefully still helps others. I encountered exactly the same problem when using SWT.VIRTUAL with an ObservableListContentProvider in combination with sorting.

The original intent of SWT.VIRTUAL is that not all elements in the contents need to be fetched to show only part of the contents. A custom content provider needs to be implemented which only has to return the elements that need to be currently shown on the screen. You also have to tell the table the total number of elements in existence. In such a use case, a table cannot be sorted in the normal way with a ViewerComparator because not all elements are known. However SWT.VIRTUAL can also be used as a performance optimization for rendering a table with many elements. This seems to work fine with the non-observable ArrayContentProvider.

But when using ObservableListContentProvider I am seeing exactly the same issue as you have. Somehow it tries to be smart and update only the elements that have actually changed. Somewhere in the depths of it's implementation something goes wrong for virtual tables, I have no clue exactly what. But I do have a solution: don't use ObservableListContentProvider at all and simply refresh the table viewer. You can e.g. use a plain ArrayContentProvider and add the following listener to the IObservableList contents of the viewer:

```
new IListChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void handleListChange(ListChangeEvent event) {
                    viewer.refresh();
                }
            };
```

I actually implemented my own "SimpleObservableListContentProvider" that does exactly this, but also takes care of switching table input by implementing the inputChanged method to remove this listener from the old input list and add it to the new one.